# Plugin loaded, but not running

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

We are using a plugin (https://github.com/ADeMen/GOOVAIN/) that is supposed to provide a 'get shortlink' button along with some database updates.

It should look like this.
[image: shortlinks]

This worked perfectly for a while. We migrated our database and content to a new server. Now whenever we create or edit a post this option is missing, but only for the *new* posts. Existing posts are fine.

[image]

I edited the source of the plugin slightly - adding a fopen dumping the behavior of the plugin (when the file is opened, functions begun, etc) to the tmp directory for analysis. The file is opened, the add_* directives are called. The defined functions are never called.

The add_filter and add_action directives look right to me.

I've checked the syslog, httpd logs, php error log and nothing gives any explanation as to what the issue is or how to fix it.

Any insight?

Comment: Did you make sure that **all** URL's in the database are changed to the new URL. Did you flush your permalinks, deactivated the plugin and reactivated it. If this does not help, contact the plugin author with these details. Support for third party plugins is off topic here

Comment: Pieter, I have been working with the plugin author and will collaborate on a solution. I'm not sure I'd call that third party

Answer (score 0):

After some extended debugging we found the issue. The plugin uses Google's url shortener api, which uses an api key for any kind of large volume. Our dev instance (more accurately the public ip assoiated with it) was under the threshold for not needing a key.

Production was over but there wasn't adequate error handling to see what had happened.  We now can provide an api key and have things function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the plugin states that because of security reasons the api key was added. I know this is old but the plugin is still alive and working.